# Where can href attribute appear in HTML document?

Tags: html

In which elements (tags) attribute **href** is allowed according to the HTML 4.01 standard?

*EDIT: An is it commonly used is some other tags (in non-standard ways).*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/index/attributes.html)...

A, AREA, LINK, BASE

Comment: +1 the only one who got it completely right in the first go :)

Comment: +1 I was going for the same thing, but I didn't know about that table.  Nice.

Comment: I was looking for exactly such table. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

primarily the Anchor tag

```
<a href="www.url.com">link</a>
```

Have a look at [www.htmlref.com](http://www.htmlref.com)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK only `<a>` and `<base>` tags allow the href attr.